# How does im2rec works? I keep getting syntax error

Tags: python, bash, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-sagemaker

I am trying to create lst files for aws image classification algorithm.
My main directory is train which has 20 sub-directories of 40 images each.
I want to create a train_1st which contains all the converted lst files.
But I am getting issues with the below code. I'm new to this .. So please help me.. what do i do?

I have tried changing the current working directory(cwd) as well. I tried setting cwd as train/ and also actual directory home/ec-2/sagemaker. Nothing helped.

```
%%bash

mkdir -p  train_lst
for i in  train/*; do
    c=`basename $i`
    mkdir -p train_lst/$c
    for j in `ls $i/*.jpg | shuf | head -n 60`; do
        mv $j train_lst/$c/
    done
done

python im2rec.py --list --recursive train train_lst/
```

```
ls: cannot access train/*/*.jpg: No such file or directory
```

Comment: It is a bash script error. It fails here: `for j in ``ls $i/*.jpg | shuf | head -n 60``; do`. You should look up how to use `bash -x` to help you to debug the bash script.

Comment: It appears that `for i in  train/*; do` is not finding any matches (in which case it'll run the loop with `i` set to "train/*"). BTW, `%%bash` is not a valid shebang line; use `#!/bin/bash` or `#!/usr/bin/env bash`. [shellcheck.net](https://www.shellcheck.net) will have several other good suggestions for you.

Answer (score 0):

The error message tells us, that the variable `i` must already contain `train/*`, i.e. an **unexpanded** glob pattern. This means that there are no subdirectories below `$PWD/train`.

You can verify this by turning on

```
shopt -s failglob
```

at the start of your script. This will print an error message, whenever a pattern can not be expanded.

BTW, what is the weird `%%bash` in your script supposed to do?

Comment: I am running a python code in jupyter notebook. %%Bash to tell the compiler its a bash script in a new cell

Comment: This is odd. *Which* compiler gets informed in that way? Python for sure has no need for this. Or is this something specific to Jupyter? The problem is that `%%bash` is illegal in bash. In any case, I strongly recommend that you test your bash program first outside the Python context.